# Build custom Route in ZF2 to pass Integer id in between the string param's

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I want to build a custom ZF2 router in my module.config.php file for a controller action that will accept urls in the form of `www.domainname.com/api/ID/users`, where `www.domainname.com/api/` and `/users` will be constant and the `ID` value changes per the request. The problem is that, when the client requests a URI/router without an ID, the project redirects to an error page.  I don't want the client to be redirected to error page, but rather just stop the request for processing the action.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please decorate better your question, I can not read it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a controller issue than a router issue.  At the beginning of your controller action when you grab the ID parameter from the route, set a default value that will get assigned to the ID variable if an ID parameter is not provided.  Then reroute (or handle in some other way) when the ID variable gets set to the default value.

```
    // at the beginning of your controller action ...

    $userID = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('ID', 0);

    if ($userID==0) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute( ... redirect to somewhere ... );
    }

    // continue on to handle valid IDs
```

This will work if the client omits an ID in the url like `www.domainname.com/api//users`.  However, it will still crash if the client omits the parameter altogether, like `www.domainname.com/api/users` because the router is looking for the parameter after `www.domainname.com/api/` to be an ID, not `'users'`.  If the parameter `/users` is always going to be constant, you should consider putting it before the `ID` parameter so you can configure your `ID` parameter to be optional, like `'route' => '/api/users[/][:ID]'`.